I am getting an exception when using Serilog.Sinks.Syslog on Apple devices
I am running into an issue when using .NET Maui and Serilog.Sinks.syslog when running on an iPhone. This does not occur on my android device or the android emulator.
The goal is to have a way to get debug messages to assist a client when they have an issue. The idea is that most of the time the logs would not be sent to the server. When instructed by support there is a procedure to change the logging level so that we can see what is happening in the mobile application.
When using the following configuration the call to
LoggerConfiguration lgc = new LoggerConfiguration();
lgc.ReadFrom.Configuration(LogCconfig);


throws a {System.TypeInitializationException}
The contents of the configuration file are.
{
  "Serilog": {
    "MinimumLevel": "Information",
    "Using": [
      "Serilog.Settings.Configuration",
      "Serilog.Sinks.Debug",
      "Serilog.Sinks.Async",
      "Serilog.Sinks.Syslog",
      "Serilog.Expressions"
    ],
    "Filter": [
      {
        "Name": "ByIncludingOnly",
        "Args": {
          "expression": "Contains(SourceContext, 'BLah Blah Blah') and not Contains(SourceContext , 'ApiService')"
        }
      }
    ],
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "Async",
        "Args": {
          "configure": [
            {
              "Name": "Debug",
              "Args": {
                "outputTemplate": "[{Timestamp:HH:mm:ss} {Level:u3}] {Message:lj} {NewLine}{Exception}"
              }
            },
            {
              "Name": "UdpSyslog",
              "Args": {
                "outputTemplate": "[<s:{SourceContext}> {Timestamp:HH:mm:ss} {Level:u3}] {Message:lj} <s:{SourceContext}>{NewLine}{Exception}",
                "host": "some Blah Blah Blah Server",
                "port": 514,
                "format": "RFC5424",
                "secureProtocols": "SecureProtocols.None",
                "appName": "BLahbLah",
                "facility": "Local3"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }

    ],
    "Enrich": [
      "FromLogContext",
      "WithExceptionDetails"
    ],
    "Properties": {
      "ApplicationName": "bLah blah blAH Mobile"
    }
  }
}

Here is the stack trace from the exception
   at System.Reflection.MethodBaseInvoker.InvokeWithManyArgs(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters)
   at Serilog.Settings.Configuration.ConfigurationReader.CallConfigurationMethods(ILookup`2 methods, IReadOnlyCollection`1 configurationMethods, Object receiver)
   at Serilog.Settings.Configuration.ConfigurationReader.ApplySinks(LoggerConfiguration loggerConfiguration)
   at Serilog.Settings.Configuration.ConfigurationReader.Configure(LoggerConfiguration loggerConfiguration)
   at Serilog.Configuration.LoggerSettingsConfiguration.Settings(ILoggerSettings settings)
   at Serilog.ConfigurationLoggerConfigurationExtensions.Configuration(LoggerSettingsConfiguration settingConfiguration, IConfiguration configuration, ConfigurationReaderOptions readerOptions)
   at blahblahblah.MauiProgram.CreateMauiApp() in C:\blahblahblahDev\repos\blahblahblah-mobile\blahblahblah\MauiProgram.cs:line 110

I tracked the culprit down by eliminating sections in the configuration and identified that the exception is coming from the async configuration section for UdpSyslog. I have also confirm that the configuration contained in LogCconfig is what i expect.
What i am expecting is that the code runs the same in both environments.
Some possible issues that i am thinking about are:

some sort of permission for the IOS environment that i don't know about.
IOS slamming me for not using TLS.
straight up problem where the serilog.sinks.syslog package is not implemented in IOS.

So my questions are:

has anyone done this before? If yes then is there a trick that I need to know about.
How would you debug issues with serilog configuration issues? There has to be a better way than downloading the code and single stepping thru to find an error in configuration. Without logging you cant log the exception. Using VS Studio i am able view the exception but the contents are not very useful.

As always any help would be greatly appreciated.
